# How to make wordpress.com login connect work with meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, meteor

I'm following these tutorial:

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/wpcc/

`https://github.com/Automattic/wpcom-connect-examples/blob/master/express.js/app.js`

So I setup `Meteor.loginWithWordpresscom` with the following code:

```
Accounts.oauth.registerService('wordpresscom');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.loginWithWordpresscom = function(options, callback) {
    // support a callback without options
    if (! callback && typeof options === "function") {
      callback = options;
      options = null;
    }

    var credentialRequestCompleteCallback = Accounts.oauth.credentialRequestCompleteHandler(callback);
    Wordpresscom.requestCredential(options, credentialRequestCompleteCallback);
  };
} else {
  Accounts.addAutopublishFields({
    forLoggedInUser: ['services.wordpresscom'],
    forOtherUsers: ['services.wordpresscom.username']
  });
}
```

And then I request credential with the following code:

```
Wordpresscom = {};

Wordpresscom.requestCredential = function (options, credentialRequestCompleteCallback) {
  if (!credentialRequestCompleteCallback && typeof options === 'function') {
    credentialRequestCompleteCallback = options;
    options = {};
  }

  var config = ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne({service: 'wordpresscom'});
  if (!config) {
    credentialRequestCompleteCallback && credentialRequestCompleteCallback(
      new ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError());
    return;
  }
  var credentialToken = Random.secret();

  var loginStyle = OAuth._loginStyle('wordpresscom', config, options);

  var loginUrl =
    'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize' +
    '?client_id=' + config.clientId +
    '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/connected' +
    '&response_type=token' +
    '&grant_type=authorization_code' +
    '&scope=global'

  OAuth.launchLogin({
    loginService: "wordpresscom",
    loginStyle: loginStyle,
    loginUrl: loginUrl,
    credentialRequestCompleteCallback: credentialRequestCompleteCallback,
    credentialToken: credentialToken,
    popupOptions: {width: 900, height: 450}
  });
};
```

At the server, I request `accessToken` and `identity` with following code:

```
Wordpresscom = {};

OAuth.registerService('wordpresscom', 2, null, function(query) {

  var accessToken = getAccessToken(query);
  var identity = getIdentity(accessToken);

  return {
    serviceData: {
      id: identity.ID,
      accessToken: OAuth.sealSecret(accessToken),
      email: identity.email,
      username: identity.username,
      displayName: identity.display_name,
      avatar: identity.avatar_URL
    },
    options: {profile: {
        name: identity.display_name,
        displayName: identity.display_name,
        avatar: identity.avatar_URL
    }}
  };
});

var getAccessToken = function (query) {
  var config = ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne({service: 'wordpresscom'});
  if (!config)
    throw new ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError();

  var response;
  try {
    response = HTTP.post(
      "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token", {
        params: {
          code: query.code,
          client_id: config.clientId,
          client_secret: OAuth.openSecret(config.secret),
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/connected',
          grant_type: 'authorization_code'
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    throw _.extend(new Error("Failed to complete OAuth handshake with WordPress.com. " + err.message),
                   {response: err.response});
  }
  if (response.data.error) { // if the http response was a json object with an error attribute
    throw new Error("Failed to complete OAuth handshake with WordPress.com. " + response.data.error);
  } else {
    console.log('getAccessToken');
    return response.data.access_token;
  }
};

var getIdentity = function (accessToken) {
  console.log('getIdentity');
  try {
    return HTTP.get(
      "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/me", {
        headers: {
            /*"User-Agent": userAgent,*/
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        params: {access_token: accessToken}
      }).data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw _.extend(new Error("Failed to fetch identity from WordPress.com. " + err.message),
                   {response: err.response});
  }
};

Wordpresscom.retrieveCredential = function(credentialToken, credentialSecret) {
  return OAuth.retrieveCredential(credentialToken, credentialSecret);
};
```

When I fire `Meteor.loginWithWordpresscom` popup window show up to ask user whether to approve or deny my app with this link `http://localhost:3000/connected?code=a8kiRGwRPC`

I get code `a8kiRGwRPC` to request `access_token`

After I approve, it redirect to `http://localhost:3000/connected#access_token=w%5EQ7CFcvZQx3t%28OjspIs84v13BsbyUGROzrYh3%23aiLJQ%25NB%2AZ7jMjNX2%29m7%23t5J4&expires_in=1209600&token_type=bearer&site_id=0`

Just like that. No new user stored in `Meteor.users` database

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Very bad rest api architecture. Just wasting time